# How can i specify the size of the image rendered by the_content();?

Tags: the-content, images

I can do it manually like this:

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'large');
```

But how can i set the size of the image rendered by `the_content();` to Large too ?

Comment: Do you mean how to set a size for the images inline with the content that comes from WordPress' text editor? If you want to force a size, you can do it via css and just target the parent wrapper that holds the_content in your css selector. If you don't want to force one size and just set a minimum or maximum, you can set a min-width/height or max-width/height in your css. Just remember that whenever you re-size images with css, you force the browser to size them therefore making your site run slower. Let me know if this is what you meant. Good luck!

Comment: Also this may help: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/image_constrain_size_for_editor

Answer (score 1):

You can use the $content_width to set the maximum width for images added to posts. You can also use this for the height.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Content_Width

If you use CSS, smaller post images may be stretched.